# Rails 3 - undefined method `last_request_at' for Assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I use Authlogic for authentication users + Omniauth for social authentication.
After creating new account for user, who signed up with Facebook, I want to set up his role in the system.

**user** model

```
 def self.create_user_from_facebook(auth_hash)
    a = self.create!({
      :facebook_uid => auth_hash["uid"],
      ...,
      :crypted_password => "facebook",
      :password_salt => "facebook",
      :persistence_token => "facebook",
      :provider => auth_hash["provider"]
    })
    puts a.errors.inspect #returns no errors, record is successfully saved
    puts a.inspect # returns: last_request_at: "2012-10-01 08:12:51"
    Assignment.create(:user_id => user.id, :role_id => 2)
  end
```

And when I try to add new record into `assignments` table this way, I get the error

```
undefined method `last_request_at' for #<Assignment:0x0000012a1539e0>
```

The column `last_request_at` is in the table `users`.

How does the column `last_request_at` from the table `users` relate with the table `assignments`? (with only these two columns: `role_id`, `user_id`)?

```
**EDIT** another information:
class UserOauthController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @current_user = User.find_or_create_from_oauth(auth_hash)

    if current_user
      UserSession.create(current_user, true)    
      flash[:success] = 'Successfully logged in.'
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash[:warning] = 'Authorization ERROR! Please, try it again.'
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible list of atteibutes

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    authlogic set up
  end

  ...validations...

  def self.find_or_create_from_oauth(auth_hash)
    provider = auth_hash["provider"]
    uid = auth_hash["uid"].to_s

    case provider      
      when 'facebook'
        if user = self.where('email = ? and provider = ?', auth_hash["info"]["email"], provider).first    
          return user
        elsif user = self.find_by_facebook_uid(uid)
          return user
        else
          return self.create_user_from_facebook(auth_hash)
        end

    end

    def self.create_user_from_facebook(auth_hash)
      a = self.create!({
        :facebook_uid => auth_hash["uid"],
        ...,
        :crypted_password => "facebook",
        :password_salt => "facebook",
        :persistence_token => "facebook",
        :provider => auth_hash["provider"]
      })
      puts a.errors.inspect
      puts a.inspect
      a.assignments.create(:role_id => MEMBER)
    end
  end
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to show more of your model, and how you are calling this method. Are you perhaps calling `last_request_at` on the `create_user_from_facebook` method? (Like `request = create_user_from_facebook(hash).last_request_at`). That method is returning an Assignment object.

Comment: @bricker hi, I updated my original question - added another information.

Comment: can you please provide the error stack trace?